# Do I miss some features if I install the MVC4 under the Framework 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The version of `asp.net-mvc4` was develop to the newest version of the framework (4.5) of the `.Net` what I want to know if I install this framework over the 4.0 framework some features are lost?

Comment: No. This is seperate library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't miss anything in the ASP.NET MVC framework, however you won't be able to use the new async features of C# which are only available with .NET 4.5. Also, if you are using Entity Framework be aware that EF's support of enums requires .NET 4.5.